# does Spring Insight need tcServer, or can it work with Eclipse and Tomcat?

Tags: spring, tcserver, spring-insight

does Spring Insight need tcServer, or can it work with Eclipse and Tomcat? I see some tutorials on Spring Insight, but all of them seem to use tcServer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, Spring Insight does not need tcServer to do its work.  It can work with JBoss and other containers.  However the easiest packaged solution for VMware is to distribute it as a template for tc Server.  VMware does not document the classpath / JVM settings / setup needed for Insight to run with other containers.  Again it's technically possible, but not currently supported.  I believe that configuration will be out as supported in the near future (within a month or 2)

Since tc Server is free for developers and essentially the same as Tomcat, why can't you use it with tc Server?  The integration is quite nice (especially with STS/Eclipse)

Comment: Yes, Tomcat and JBoss will be officially supported in a few months